# Why are visualizations not appearing on the correct nodes in Code Workbook?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

I have a code workbook in which I create several plots using Matplotib:
[image]

If I run all downstream from my data-dataset the plots are not shown at the expected node, sometimes they do not contain any plots and sometimes some of the nodes contain more than one visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because matplotlib is not thread safe.
By adding `@synchronous_node_execution` to each of the plot_-code workbook nodes, you can lock each node to ensure the visualization is shown on the correct node:

```
# plot 1 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@synchronous_node_execution
def plot_1(data):
    df = data
    [...]
```